# How can I copy file once and paste into multiple subfolders?

Tags: windows, copy-paste

I have `file.xpi`.

I want to copy and paste it into a folders named `extensions`.

This folder `extensions` is a subdirectory in multiple folders.
I mean I have multiple folders, and every one of them has an `extensions` folder.

I want to paste the file into each of these `extensions` folders.

How can I do that?

Comment: Copy it once then paste it in each folder you want it in

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you copy(or cut) anything it goes to the `Clipboard` remains there until you copy/cut anything else.
In your case you are just copying so you can paste it as many locations as you wish.
**[NOTE]** Be careful when you **cut** because it is not the same in that case.

Hope it hels. :)